# Mercurial - Add tag to committed files on commit

Tags: mercurial, commit, mercurial-hook

We are looking for a way to add / update a custom tag at the beginning of each file being committed during a commit. Its some kind of local timestamp we need.

I was thinking of hooks.

Unfortunately I cannot find a useful hook for that:

1. `precommit`: unsuitable as it fires **before** hg knows any metadata of the commit
2. `pretxncommit`: unsuitable, as the documentation clearly states that we should not change the working dir at this point
3. `commit`: unsuitable, as it fires when the commit has already happened.

EDIT:

I can not use hg's inline changeset-hash and / or datetime. For the following reason:
Our files get later imported into an external system (we do not have control over) which does not support any kind of versioning.

To simplify stuff: let's say **tag** is an ever-incrementing no. (everytime we commit). This tag is then used to help getting an idea of the version / status of the file **on the system** in respect to the **file in the repo** - like "no. of changes we're missing" and such.

Any ideas?

Comment: The commit itself already 'tags' everything with an sha hash, a timestamp, commit message, authorname and all changes made - and that can be conveniently queried. What's your usecase?

Comment: I've updated my question with the use-case.

Comment: What if two people commit to the same file on their own computers, with your system both would have the same incremented number, yet the files are different.

Comment: I know. The idea is that the tag is actually the no. of commits made on this file. Fil is at 0. Mine gets 1. Other also gets 1. I merge: it becomes 3. (mine + other + merge). Ugly, I know.

Comment: What kind of files are you committing, and what do you mean by "at the beginning of each file"?

Comment: They are really just plain text files - in a format the external system understands. It's source code. But each file has a "meta"-section where we can freely write some properties to. That's where I'd place my tag in. Because this meta-section is easily accessible once the file is imported.

Comment: if it's just the modification count (and not hash) you want, you can do that in the pre-commit hook. See addition to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is - to my knowledge - no intrinsic system in mercurial which supports what you describe. However I can recommend an approach which somewhat is adopted from building a software release package from the repository: Make a small export script which replaces a certain KEYWORD in your files with the version information you need. A Makefile target could look like which creates a zip export for revision XXX with version information in all files which support it (thus contain the verbatim KEYWORD - use something truely unique here):

```
VERSION=$(hg log -rXXX --template="Version: {node|short} from {date|isodate}")

export:
  hg archive -rXXX -t files export
  for i in $(hg ma -rXXX); do sed -i "s/KEYWORD/$VERSION/g" $i; done
  zip -9rq export.zip export
```

I use a similar approach in my Makefiles where I create versioned export for the source of a particular revision of my software.

EDIT: if your purpose (as stated by the comment) is only to implant the number of commits made to that file: then you can use indeed a pre-commit hook and modify the file. You can count the number of modifications made to a file with `hg log FILENAME --template="{node}\n" | wc -l`. Do that for every file and do the sed replacement in the header of each file in the pre-commit hook.

Comment: While this was also an initial idea of ours, it has one flaw: it changes the contents of the file **after** the commit. Which results in differences if I compare the file from **system** and **repository**. Not that ideal.

Comment: Alternatively use *one* file which ships along with the export which only contains the revision information. However, with the described approach, the difference is predictable (as it only depends on the commit), thus a comparison is easy to do, too (as you know the expected diff).

Comment: My company specifically requested that people "want to see an incremental no. per file". Even if I'd handle it through the dedicated file, it would still need to apply the version to each files before importing them. And I would still have "different" files after that operation.
I understand your point that the diff is predictable, but still. It creates a lot of noise that distracts.

Comment: "want to see an incremental no. per file" <-- you want to use subversion then. For distributed version control systems like hg and git sequential numbering of commits is local to a specific repository at best; already its clones will differ.

Comment: No, really. I don't want to. I am well aware of the differences. We are developing distributed, we heavily use the features a DVCS provides. We just somehow need to have some kind of version indication on the target system - per file.

Comment: Regarding your latest EDIT: That's exactly what I want to do. But the pre-commit hook **does not provide** the files I am going to commit.

Comment: A bit hackish: Use hg status to gather the changed files in the pre-commit hook. Though that might fail when only some files are being committed.

Comment: OK, I will try that out. Our repositories typically contain between 3000 to 4000 files. So going through all of them is overkill. On the other hand: Most of the time all the "dirty" files in the working dir are actually getting committed on the next commit. So doing this only on the result of `hg status` might work. Will give it a shot. Hopefully hg doesn't complain.

Comment: for log: `-r .` will be nicer, `rfc3339date` filter - shorter and more readable. But even just `{node|short}` is sufficient ID, or (with minimal tagging "deployed -tagged") `{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}-{node|short}` (trailing part for branchpoints only)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a two-stage solution. First, create an alias along the following lines:

```
[alias]
tcommit = !tag-changed-files && $HG commit "$@"
```

Here, `tag-changed-files` would retrieve a list of modified and added/moved files via `$HG status -ma -n` or `$HG status -ma -n -0` and tag them. I am assuming that re-tagging files that have been modified but aren't being committed yet is a harmless operation; more on that below. Note that you can even redefine commit if you absolutely want to via:

```
[alias]
commit = !tag-changed-files && $HG --config alias.commit=commit commit "$@"
```

However, this is potentially problematic, because it may confuse scripts.

You could also integrate the commit step in the program if you wanted to, and even try and parse the command line arguments to only tag those files that you are committing. For this approach, using [hglib](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PythonHglib) might be appropriate to avoid the overhead of invoking Mercurial multiple times. (Note that hglib and other tools that use the [command server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer) ignore aliases and command defaults, so this works even if you alias commit).

Second, you'd install a `pretxncommit` hook that verifies that files that are being committed have indeed been tagged appropriately (to ensure that the `tag-changed-files` program hasn't been bypassed by accident).

This should work without a problem on full commits; for partial commits, any files that were changed but have not been committed would also have been retagged, but since they will be either committed later (and get tagged properly at that point) or reverted, that should be harmless.

Comment: In our case, a commit can happen from various sources. Be it a "normal" commit, a graft, a merge, a rebase ... Therefore I'd rather stick to hooks than overriding / adding new commands. Besides: I cannot trust my developers to use tcommit instead of commit ecc. But +1 for pointing out that I can override "commit" itself. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

> an idea of the version / status of the file on the system in respect to the file in the repo

Just one idea

## Stop reinvent the wheel

Incremental counter is *just shit*, if you task is "to know, which version is on LIVE and which - in Mercurial's tip" (and **this is your real business-task**, yes?!)

[Keyword Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension) give you last changes *per file*.

If you want to inject *changeset of repository* into files (it's reasonable good way), re-read this part of wiki-page

> If you just want to version your entire repo, do not use this
>   extension but let your build system take care of it. Something along
>   the lines of
>
> ```
> hg -q id > version
> ```
>
> before distribution might be well enough if file-wise keyword
>   expansion in the source is not absolutely required

You can insert `hg id` output into files at export stage (in planetmaker's sed-style), bu you can also have this additional metadata in files permanently in VCS with special [encode|decode filters](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#decode-encode)